# String.at() not comparing to character ' '

Tags: c++, string, while-loop

I am writing a C++ function that takes in a string of the form "let_varname_=_20" and then it will isolate "varname" to make a new string with my name variable name. I am trying to tell the .at() function to stop iterating through a while loop when it hits a space (the underscores are spaces, I just wanted it to be abundantly clear there was a space). However, it isn't comparing them properly, as it goes to the end of the string completely without stopping (passing by 2 spaces).

```
void store(std::string exp) {


int finalcount = 4;
char placeholder = ' ';
while (exp.at(finalcount)!=placeholder) {

    finalcount++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < exp.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << exp.at(i) << std::endl;
}


std::string varname = exp.substr(4, finalcount+1);

std::cout << finalcount + 1 << std::endl;
std::cout << varname << std::endl;


}
```

I started at index 4 because I know that indexes 0-3 of teh string will be 'l' 'e' 't' and ' '. The print statements were just me checking to see what it was reading versus what I input (and it was reading everything fine, just not comparing properly). I also tried have my while loop condition say while the char was >65 && <90 to work with ASCII codes but that also didn't work.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Where's a copy paste version of this? I feel like you 10k > users have some secret copy paste stash.

Comment: The only reason I asked on Stack Overflow was because I tried everything to my knowledge, and my problem was stated in text.

Comment: @GillBates Of course that's a stock comment. I'm using [Insert Snippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/insert-snippet/nfhllbdppejecjnhnjjagjhpcbjhkcpf?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) for this. Very useful. DV, CV, leave the appropriate snippet comment.

Comment: Please look up what [`string::substr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) does, the second value isn't what you think it is; `str.substr(a, b)` actually starts at `a` and grabs the next `b` characters, it doesn't take the substring from `a` to `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `istringstream` and treat the string as a stream:

```
const std::string test_data = "let varname = 20";
std::istringstream test_stream(test_data);
std::string let_text;
std::string var_name;
char equals_sign;
unsigned int value;
test_stream >> let_text >> var_name >> equals_sign >> value;
```

This may be a lot easier than your code.

**Edit 1: Searching the string**
You could also use the `std::string` methods, `find_first_of` and `find_first_not_of`.

```
std::string::size_type position = test_data.find_first_of(' ');
position = test_data.find_first_not_of(' ', position);
std::string::size_type end_position = test_data.find_first_of(' ');
let_text = test_data.substr(position, end_position - position);
```

Comment: Using this, do I need to include any special library? Also, will let_text == "let"? and var_name == "varname" ? and value == 20?

Comment: No extra libraries required.

Comment: Thank you for your help Thomas.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please click on the check mark.

Comment: I tried, and it made me wait 2 minutes. Just did it now. Thanks again.

Comment: Please do not beg for accepts, particularly after only 8 minutes. We should be encouraging people to wait and watch for new information.

Comment: Thomas, I am taking in the 'value' variable you listed as a string in my code due to parsing reasons. Will value stop reading a line if a whitespace is encountered? Is there a way to get it to read the whole rest of the string?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you aren't using `substr()` properly, as I mentioned in a comment.  Also, as [Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker) mentioned in a comment, you should also be checking for `=` and stopping when you reach the end of the string, so that you don't overrun your string if there aren't any more spaces in it.  Additionally, you don't want to add 1 to `finalcount` when determining substring length, because then your substring will include the space or `=` that made the check fail.

Try this:

```
void store(std::string exp) {
    const int start = 4;          // <-- Enter starting position here.
    const char placeholder_space = ' '; // Check for space.
    const char placeholder_equal = '='; // Check for equals sign, as pointed out by Pete Becker.

    int finalcount = start;       // <-- Use starting position.
    bool found = false;

    while (finalcount < exp.size() && !found) {
        if (!((exp.at(finalcount) == placeholder_space) ||
              (exp.at(finalcount) == placeholder_equal))) {
            finalcount++;
        } else {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        std::cout << "Input is invalid.\n"; // No ' ' or '=' found, put error message here.
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < exp.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << exp.at(i) << std::endl;
    }

    std::string varname = exp.substr(4, finalcount - start); // <-- Use starting position.

    std::cout << finalcount - start << std::endl; // Length of varname.
    std::cout << varname << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You might want to modify the code to fix another bug in the original code. If the input string is, say, `"let varname=20"` (i.e., with no space characters in the text being searched) the first loop will run off the end of the string and throw an exception.

Comment: Um, you took the text in my example too literally. The problem is that the search never checks for the end of the input text, so if it gets fed `"abcdefg"` it will run off the end. Don't check for `=`; check that `finalcount` is less than `exp.size()`.

Comment: ...Oh.  I didn't even notice that, somehow.  Thanks, I'll fix it.  \*sheepish laugh\*